# Defining a task without firing it parallel

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Hello is there any way to define tasks without firing them ?
I need to get hold of a task object without it to fire.

```
 ------code-------------
    Task A=Task.Run(func1);
    Task B=Task.Run(func2);
    -----some more code----
```

In this example the `A` task gets fired right in the  line that is defined, in parallel(on another core whatever) from the rest of the program.

I want to be able to  dictate when Task B is fired according to A but still parallel from the rest of the program.

```
Something like :
    ---code---
    Task A= something without starting it
    Task B= something without starting it

    B.ContinueWith(A);
    ---code----
```

P.S i want to orchestrate some tasks in parallel from the main thread,and for this case i do not need `Task.WhenAll/When Any`

Comment: Sounds like you actually just want a delegate / lambda.

Comment: No , i understand i can use lambdas etc..i wanted to know if i can define them somewhere (they are many) and just fire them at will.

Comment: Huh? You can define lambdas anywhere you want.  Or normal functions.

Comment: I wanted to know if i can write the tasks in one line without starting them.`Task a=Task.Run(()=>Console.WriteLine("test"));` Is there anyway to not write something like `Task a` then define the method somewhere else...and then wrap it up `a=Task.Run(mymethod);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Func<Task>` like this:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var methodToInvoke = new Func<Task>(() => MyMethod())

    // Later on
    await methodToInvoke();
}

async Task MyMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Well that's the good thing of StackOverflow then, isn't it :-)

Comment: Should i delete this question if you think its bad or useless ?

Comment: No, I think it is useful for others as well. You are not the first and probably not the last to want this behavior and not all know about Func.

Comment: Yes i need a wrap around the Task =))